# Portainer agent on EC2 machine not deploying

Tags: docker-swarm, portainer

I have a fresh AWS EC2 machine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server) which is a master of a Docker swarm. I am trying to deploy Portainer agent to monitor my stack remotely.

If I follow the [official guide](https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/ceinstallswarm/), issuing the commands:

```
docker network create portainer_agent_network
docker service create --name portainer_agent --network portainer_agent_network --publish mode=host,target=9001,published=9001 -e AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR=tasks.portainer_agent --mode global --mount type=bind,src=//var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock --mount type=bind,src=//var/lib/docker/volumes,dst=/var/lib/docker/volumes --mount type=bind,src=/,dst=/host portainer/agent
```

I get the error:

```
Error: No such network: portainer_agent_network
```

Didn't I just create the mentioned network? What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the network should be `attachable`. Create it with:

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable portainer_agent_network
```